# jQuery nested accordion with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-accordion

I have been trying to work with jQuery nested accordion and JSON object.

I have tried to build the hierarchy successfully. For some reason however when I click the child element accordion, the entire accordion collapses.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have more than one element with same id "accordion" so the function is executing on the first accordion element

Comment: @ADASein, Thanks for your reply. But then how can i generate dynamic accordion nested element tags? And in the HTML it will always have one div with accordion ID as i will not know the number of nested child accordions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
mangoServiceList += '<div class="accordion" ><h4><li>'+ mangoServ.name +'</li></h4><div>' + mangoServ.description+ '</div></div>';
```

Notice now it's not id but class

and then add the funcionality

```
 $(".accordion").each(function(){
    $(this).accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false
    });
 });
```

Check new jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zza6L4v/

Comment: Should i change the HTML attribute as well from id to class?